# mvc asp.net ajax redirects to partial view but displays true in a blank page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, azure

I have a view page where I am calling another view page to be rendered partially in a progress bar, using javascript. On click of next button in Contact page partially rendered in abc page, I am supposed to save contact page and move to next page ThankYou and display that, but it redirects to Contact Page and displays only 'true in a blank page'. I tried to build this application with different versions of jQuery, not sure what the problem is.

-------------------------View1--------abc page-----------------

```
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "abc";
}

@{Html.RenderPartial("_progressBar");}
@{Html.RenderPartial("_Contact");}
@{Html.RenderPartial("_ThankYou");}
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "UIS", null, new { @class = "button" })
 <div id="modelOTPform">
 @{Html.RenderPartial("_otpForm");}
 </div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery/myjavascript")
```

----------------------------------View2-----------Contact page------------------------

```
@model myObjectLibrary.ContactObjects
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact page";

}

<div class="module module-form">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Contact", "UIS", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnComplete = "HideThisAndShowNext(formContact)" }, new { id = "formContact" }))
    {
        <fieldset>
            <ol>
                <li>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name) @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name, "", new { @class = "error" })</li>
                 </ol>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="uisNextButton">
            @*<input type="button" value="Previous" class = "button" onclick="PreviousFormEvent('formContact')" />*@
            <input type="submit" value="Next" class="button rightButton" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Now in myjavascript.js that is in the scripts folder in WebRole, I have a HideThisAndShowNext function.

```
function HideThisAndShowNext(e) {
    HandleFormVisibility(e.id, false);
}

function HandleFormVisibility(formID,isInitialLoad) {
    $("form").parent().hide();
    $("form[id='" + formID + "']").parent().show();
    if (!isInitialLoad) {
       // alert(FetchNextFformID(formID, true));
        $("form").parent().hide();
        $("form[id='" + FetchNextFformID(formID, true) + "']").parent().show();
        //HandleProgressBar(isInitialLoad);
        HandleStatuBarClassicWay(isInitialLoad);
        BuilMarkup(formID);
    }
}

function BuilMarkup(formID) {
    if (formID == "formContact") {
        var _name = $("#formContact input#name").val();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found teh resoluition finally!!

Added this in the shared layout page.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```